# Using Angular 2 without Server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, angular, local

I'm currently working on a user interface for an Eclipse & IntelliJ plugin which should work within a SWT Browser instance. Therefore everything has to be written in HTML and JavaScript, but has to work locally.

I wanted to try out Angular 2, but it seems to be a very big problem, that I won't have my files hosted on a server, because of all the internally used XHR requests. Is there any way I could trick it into working without having to deliver a local server (which would be kind of a overkill)?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Try to check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223555/how-to-use-angular2-systemjs-locally-without-node-js-npm It might be useful for you too.

Comment: There are complete repositories that use a local server for development, but are also able to create a productive build that creates only html and js: https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed

Comment: Will the created build be able to run locally without the development server? Because your proposed repo doesn't really look like it would solve my problem.
I don't mind developing with a local server at all - the problem that I have is, that I don't want to distribute my code with a server...

Comment: When you create the productiv build, you can copy paste it and just open the index.html

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot! I will give it a try!

Comment: check out this issue in github https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10137